# Add a additional condition to Case Statement in Switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is it possible to add a additional Condition to Switch Statement like below in C#

```
switch(MyEnum)
{ 
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3 && Year > 2012://Additional Condtion Here
       //Do Something here..........
      break; 
  case 4:
  case 5:
       //Do Something here..........
      break;  
 }
```

In above mentioned example if **MyEnum = 3** then it has to be excuted if **Year > 2012**... Is it possible?

[EDITED]

**Year > 2012 is not applicable to case 1 & case 2.**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order for it to work the way you've indicated with the fallthrough logic for 1 and 2, I'd suggest moving the `//do something here` portion out to a method or function and then doing this:

```
  case 1:
  case 2:
      DoSomething();
      break;
  case 3:
      if(Year > 2012) { DoSomething(); }
      break;
```

The other alternative would be:

```
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
      if (MyEnum != 3 || Year > 2012) {
         // Do something here
      }
      break;
```

but I think the first option is much more intuitive and readable.

Comment: SWITCH..CASE with IF statement inside is a bad idea, because both are selection control statement, we don't mixed it.

Answer (score 27):

C#7 new feature:

case...when

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7

```
public static int DiceSum4(IEnumerable<object> values)
{
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case int val:
                sum += val;
                break;
            case IEnumerable<object> subList when subList.Any():
                sum += DiceSum4(subList);
                break;
            case IEnumerable<object> subList:
                break;
            case null:
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("unknown item type");
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no.

You'll need the following:

```
switch (MyEnum)
{
   case 1:
   case 2:
       DoSomething();
       break;
   case 3:
       if (Year > 2012) DoSomething();
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add condition to a case. Case clause has to be a **compile time constant**. Instead you can use an if statement inside the case statement.

```
case 3:
      if( > 2012)
       {
       //Do Something here..........
       }
break;
```

Comment: In that case code may be repeatative for Case 1,2 and Case 3.

Comment: @Anandkumar if the >2012 condition applies to many or all case statements, you can wrap the swich in a `if`

Comment: @Anandkumar, no it will first compare the MyEnum, if its 3, then it will jump to the case statement 3, where it will check for year. If you have to check for year for all cases then use a if statement on the switch

Comment: @Habib His point is that the way you have it, the >2012 check would occur when MyEnum is 1, 2, or 3, but he only wants the > 2012 limitation when MyEnum is 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the if condition inside your case , you can't use && in case statement, use like below:

```
switch(MyEnum)
{ 
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3: //Additional Condtion Here
  if (Year > 2012)
  {     
      //Do Something here..........
  }
  break; 
  case 4:
  case 5:
       //Do Something here..........
      break;  
 }
```

Comment: He wants Year > 2012 to only apply to case: 3.

Comment: In your case 
if (Year > 2012)
  {     
      //Do Something here..........
  } is applicable to all three casee case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you can add the condition to the switch:

```
switch (MyEnum!=3 || Year>2012 ? MyEnum : -1)
{ 
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
       //Do Something here..........
      break; 
  case 4:
  case 5:
       //Do Something here..........
      break;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I do something like that...

(sorry for the naming, the use case didn't inspire me)

Considering those private classes:

```
private class NumberState
{
    public static NumberState GetState(int number, int year)
    {
        if (number == 1) 
            return new FirstNumberState();
        if (number == 2) 
            return new FirstNumberState();
        if (number == 3 && year > 2012) 
            return new FirstNumberState();

        if (number == 4) 
            return new SecondNumberState();
        if (number == 5) 
            return new SecondNumberState();

        return new DefaultNumberState();
    }
}

private class FirstNumberState : NumberState { }
private class SecondNumberState : NumberState { }
private class DefaultNumberState : NumberState { }
```

Then you can do:

```
switch (NumberState.GetState(MyEnum, Year))
{
    case FirstNumberState _:
        // do something
        break;

    case SecondNumberState _:
        // do something
        break;

    case DefaultNumberState _:
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unhandled number state");
}
```

It's easy to read even when your conditions get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# 8 feature

```
        public static bool SomeHelper(int value)
            => value switch
            {
                100 => true,
                var x when x >= 200 && x <= 300 => true,
                _ => false, // All other values
            };
```

You will have `true` with values 100, 200...300 and `false` with other values

Also you can use params:

```
        public static bool SomeHelper(int value, bool param)
            => value switch
            {
                100 => true,
                var x when x >= 200 && x <= 300 && param => true,
                _ => false, // All other values
            };
```

in this case you will have `true` only if `value` is 100 and `param` is false